# className.type does not have a member called 'appDel'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a reference to my app delegate

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as AppDelegate
```

That works just fine, but this line of code below gives a error:

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

It gives me the following error:

```
'vctGebruikers.Type' does not have a member named 'appDel'
```

I declared them right below my class like this:

```
class vctGebruikers: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as AppDelegate
  let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext 
}
```

The weird thing is when I paste the code in `viewDidLoad` or in a function the code just works fine. And I can't figure out what the problem is.
How can I solve this error?

EDIT:
I also need to acces context here:

```
let results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
```

This is what I got working thanks to @Antonio, but now im not able to acces context and appDel

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
  let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as AppDelegate
  self.appDel = appDelegate
  self.context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: make `appDel` a computed `get` property - it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

In swift you cannot reference `self` until all class properties have been initialized.
You are implicitly using `self` in this line:

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
```

The solution is to initialize them in an initializer, but using something like:

```
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate) as AppDelegate
self.appDel = appDelegate
self.context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

Also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24654560/), a similar question asked a couple days ago on SO.

Comment: That works thanks, but I need to acces appDel and Context take a look at my updated question.

Comment: well, if `results` is another class property, then the same thing applies to it. You are implicitly using `self` during its initialization. Just create another `let ctx = appDelegate.managedObjectContext` support variable and use that to initialize both `self.context` and `self.results`

Answer (score 0):

One method of instantiating the context is to drill down instead of up from AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let vc = window?.rootViewController as? UIViewController {   
        vc.context = self.managedObjectContext}
```

`

And in your view controller, tell it to populate dynamically

`var context: NSManagedObjectContext!`

Also don't forget to call
`import CoreData` everywhere you are using said objects

One more final method: Use a closure so that your reference will happen at run time:

    `var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    }`