# Swift class does not recognize its property

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am trying to write my first Swift program. I just created a class and added a couple of constant properties. Now on of those properties holds a reference to another object. But seems like my class is not recognizing the stored property and I am getting the following error:

"ConnectivityManager.Type does not have a member named 'peerId'

My code is following:

```
class ConnectivityManager {

let peerId: MCPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name);
let advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerId, discoveryInfo:nil, serviceType: "MP_SWIFT"); }
```

I am probably doing something stupid. I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me what am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [swift global constants: cannot use another constant for initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654560/swift-global-constants-cannot-use-another-constant-for-initialization)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use another property in your initialization you have to use an init method.

```
class ConnectivityManager {

    let peerId: MCPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name);
    let advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser
    init(){
        advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerId, discoveryInfo:nil, serviceType: "MP_SWIFT");
    }
}
```